# Execute Function within a TabItem Content? C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am pretty illiterate with C#. I write mostly in scripting languages. Bear with me please.

I have a TabControl in my application. TabItems on this TabControl are added progmatically based on input from the user. The contents of each TabItem is a UserControl. I have a whole bunch of UserControls. For the sake of simplification, this is how I am adding a TabItem to my TabControl:

```
TabItem tab = new TabItem();

tab.Name = "myTab";
tab.Header = "My Tab";

switch (type)
{
    case "type1": tab.Content = new MyTab1(); break;
    case "type2": tab.Content = new MyTab2(); break;
    case "type3": tab.Content = new MyTab3(); break;
}

tabControl.Items.Add(tab);
```

Each TabItem builds it's own info. Here is an example of one of the UserControls:

```
public partial class MyTab1 : UserControl
{
    public MyTab1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string getInfo()
    {
        return "this is a test of MyTab1 info";
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to poll each tab for that info through a WebSocket Server. Basically, the user submits the name of a tab; the system should then echo out the results of `getInfo()` for that UserControl.

This is how far I've gotten so far...

```
Generic.sockets = new List<Fleck.IWebSocketConnection>();
Generic.websock = new Fleck.WebSocketServer("ws://0.0.0.0:58341");
Generic.websock.Start(socket =>
{
    socket.OnOpen = () => Generic.sockets.Add(socket);
    socket.OnClose = () => Generic.sockets.Remove(socket);
    socket.OnMessage = message =>
    {
        foreach (TabItem item in tabControl.Items)
        {
            if (Dispatcher.Invoke(() => item.Name) == message)
            {
                // this is where I need to echo out the getInfo() function
                MessageBox.Show(?????);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Normally you would bind data to a TabItem and then you would look at the DataContext.  eg. item.DataContext as ( viewModelObject )... then call viewModelObject.getInfo()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good opportunity to learn about interfaces, which will tell the compiler that each of your custom user controls supports the getInfo() method.  If all your controls implement the same interface then you don't have to worry about which type of object you're dealing with.

Start by defining an interface like this:

```
public interface IGetInfo
{
    string getInfo();
}
```

Next, each of your user controls need to implement the interface in its declaration:

```
public partial class MyTab1 : UserControl, IGetInfo
{
    ...
}
```

Finally, when it's time to call getInfo(), just cast the object as the shared interface (IGetInfo) and call getInfo() normally:

```
foreach (TabItem item in tabControl.Items)
{
    if (Dispatcher.Invoke(() => item.Name) == message)
        ((IGetInfo)item.Content).getInfo();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could cast the `Content` of a `TabItem` to your type wih the `getInfo()` method:

```
socket.OnMessage = message =>
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
    {
        foreach (TabItem item in tabControl.Items)
        {
            if (item.Name == message)
            {
                MyTab1 tab1 = item.Content as MyTab1;
                if(tab1 != null)
                    MessageBox.Show(tab1.getInfo());
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Since the `Content` property may return a `MyTab1`, `MyTab2` or a `MyTab3` you either need to move the `getInfo()` method to a common base class for all these types or define an interface that they all implement or find a way to map a name to a specific type so you actually know what type to cast to.